# I have written a code in python of multiple functions. I'm unit testing my code but the main function is repeating itself

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, dictionary

I have created a program of online selling system. It has a main menu and some options. I have implemented each component as a function. But when I'm running it goes well and shows me the main menu but when I select any option it displays the main menu again. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, I'm just a beginner. Here is code;

```
def main_menu(): 
    print("=======================================================")
    print("\t\tWelcome to our online System")
    print("=======================================================")
    print("<1> List the available services")
    print("<2> Search for a service")
    print("<3> Purchase a service")
    print("<4> List my services")
    print("<5> Quit ")
    selected_option = int(input("Please select an option from the above:"))
    return selected_option

all_services = { '1': ['MS Word', '$20'], '2':['Photoshop', '$120'],
                  '3':['Music player','$89'], '4': ['Photo Advance', '$99'],
                  }

def option1(argu):
    print('\nThe available services and applications are:\n')                
    for key, value in all_services.items():
        print(key, '-', value[0])
    print("\nThank You!")
def option2():
    service_search = input("\nPlease enter the service name you want to search or a negative number to exit:")
    search_result = {}
    for id, name in all_services.items():
        if service_search in name[0].replace(" ","").lower():
            search_result[id] = name 
    if len(search_result) > 0:
    print('\n',len(search_result), 'services have been found:\n')
    for key, val in search_result.items():
        print('Service ID:', key, '\nService Name:', val[0], '\nCost:', val[1])
    else:
        print('This service is not available')
    another_search = input('Do you want to search for another course (Y/N)?')
    if another_search == 'Y':
        option2()
    elif another_search == 'N':
        main_menu()
    else:
        print('Exit')
def option3():
    print("The available services are:\n")
    for id, name in all_services.items():
        print(id,'-' ,name[0])
    select_option = input('\nPlease select the service code you want to purchase or a negative number to exit:')
    print('\nservice detail:\nName:',all_services[select_option][0], '\nCost:', all_services[select_option][1])
    confirm_purchase = input('\nDo you want to buy this service (Y/N)?')
    if confirm_purchase == 'Y':
        print('Please enter your name and your credit card details:\n')
        customer_name = input('Name: ')
        card_no = input('Card Number: ')
        card_expmo = input('MM: ')
        card_expy = input('YYYY:')
        with open('customer.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(customer_name + select_option + all_services[select_option][0]+ all_services[select_option][1])
        print('Thank You!\nYou have been purchasing the ',all_services[select_option][0],'.')
        another_purchase = input('Do you want to purchase another service (Y/N)?')
        if another_purchase == 'Y':
           option3()
        else:
           print('Thankyou for purchasing from our online shop')
    elif confirm_purchase == 'N':
        print('\n')
        main_menu()
    else:
        print('Exit')
def option4():
    name_search = input('Please enter your name to search:')
    with open('/content/customer.txt', 'r') as info:
        purchase_details = []
        for line in info:
            line_list = line.split(',')
            purchase_details.append(line_list)
        for i in range(len(purchase_details)):
            if name_search in purchase_details[i][0]:
                print('Hello', name_search,'you have purchased the following:\n')
                print(i,'-',purchase_details[i][2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main_menu()
  if main_menu() == 1:
    option1(all_services)
  elif main_menu() == 2:
    option2()
  elif main_menu() == 3:
    option3()
  elif main_menu() == 4:
    option4()
  elif main_menu() == 5:
    print('Goodbye')
  else:
    print('Please enter a valid option')
```

Following is the output I'm getting from the above code;

```
=======================================================
         Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
=======================================================
        Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
=======================================================
        Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
=======================================================
        Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
=======================================================
        Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
=======================================================
        Welcome to our online System
=======================================================
<1> List the available services
<2> Search for a service
<3> Purchase a service
<4> List my services
<5> Quit 
Please select an option from the above:5
Goodbye
```

Comment: btw you have some recursive calls. These are not appropriate for your program. You should replace them with some sort of `while` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you write `main_menu()` you call the `main_menu` function and cause the menu to 'repeat itself'.

Try:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  choice = main_menu()
  if choice == 1:
    option1(all_services)
  elif choice == 2:
    option2()
  elif choice == 3:
    option3()
  elif choice == 4:
    option4()
  elif choice == 5:
    print('Goodbye')
  else:
    print('Please enter a valid option')
```

Note that we only write `main_menu()` once, so it is only called once. This will fix at least the repeating problem.

You might also want to consider adding a `while` loop to allow the user to continue using the menu after finishing with an option:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  while True:  
    choice = main_menu()
    if choice == 1:
      option1(all_services)
    elif choice == 2:
      option2()
    elif choice == 3:
      option3()
    elif choice == 4:
      option4()
    elif choice == 5:
      print('Goodbye')
      break
    else:
      print('Please enter a valid option')
```

Comment: You should wrap this code in a `while True:` loop and add a `break` to option 5.

Comment: @quamrana there's a whole load of improvements that could be made to the original program; plus, to do that would be to make an assumption about what the OP wants. This is the minimal fix for the problem of 'repeating'.

Comment: I quite agree with the sentiment of you providing a minimal fix. Its just that the code you present doesn't quite work in the sense that the final line implies the user will see the main menu again. Adding the two lines I suggest will fix this.

Comment: @quamrana How about this?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Now the OP can look into all the other problems. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I've got rid of the repeating problem. What edits can I make to make my program work better please suggest.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaZaheer: You will need to ask another question that refers to any specific symptoms you see after making the changes in this answer. For example, in options 2 and 3 you can reply no to a question and you will see the main menu again, but the program won't show you the next option you select.